# Prove that $P(E|F)=P(E|F\cap G)P(G|F)+P(E|F\cap G^c)P(G^c|F)$

Tags: probability

I seek to prove the equality $P(E|F)=P(E|F\cap G)P(G|F)+P(E|F\cap G^c)P(G^c|F)$ directly, but I'm not sure how to cancel event $G$ out of the right hand side. I was able to reduce the RHS to

$$\frac{1}{P(F)}\bigl(P(E\cap (F\cap G))+P(E\cap (F\cap G^c))\bigr)$$

I know that $P(E\cap (F\cap G))+P(E\cap (F\cap G^c))=P(E\cap F)$, but I don't know how to show it. Once I show that, I can reach the equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E\cap F=\left((E\cap F)\cap G\right)\bigcup \left((E\cap F)\cap G^c\right)$ and this is a disjoint union. Indeed, $E\cap F\cap G\subset G$, $E\cap F\cap G^c\subset G^c$ and $G\cap G^c=\emptyset$.

You also know that if $A\cap B=\emptyset$, then $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure how to show that they're disjoint, though--unless ISBIO (it should be intuitively obvious).

Comment: I edited my answer, is this clearer now?

Comment: Yes! +1 for extra clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. To proceed, note that by definition of conditional probability
$$\mathbb{P}(E \cap (F \cap G)) = \mathbb{P}(E \ | \ F \cap G)\mathbb{P}(F \cap G).$$